# Why these two definitions on Independence of two variables equivalent?

Tags: probability

> The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are said to independent if, for any
> two sets of real numbers $A$ and $B$,
>
> $$P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)$$
>
> It can be shown by using the three axioms of probability that the
> equation will follow if and only if, for any $a, b \in R$: $$P(X \leq
> a, Y \leq b) = P(X \leq a)P(Y \leq b)$$

I have no clue how to proceed. It seems counter-intuitive! How to prove this exactly?

Comment: How much of measure theory have you studied? Do you know that the Borel $\sigma-$ algebra is generated by intervals of the type $(-\infty,a]$? Have you studied the $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem?

Comment: None of that. It's weird that "first course in Probability"(the book title) include such things :/ @geetha290krm

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information which can be conveyed via text.  Ref: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/ .

Comment: @XanderHenderson I did edit the question. Please reopen it.

Comment: You have accepted an answer. Why reopen that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the first one implies the second one, simply take $A=(-\infty,a)$ and $B=(-\infty,b)$.

The second one does not really imply the first one, it does only if the sets $A$ and $B$ are 'nice' (the technical term is 'Borel set'), and in fact, it does not even make sense to talk about $\Pr(X\in A)$ if $A$ is not a Borel set. Anyway, a Borel set is roughly any set that you can form using open intervals, and the operations $\cup$, $\cap$ and $\setminus$ (you can even take an union/intersection of uncountably many open intervals). First, note that for any open interval $(a,b)$,
$$\Pr(X\in(a,b))=\Pr(X\leq b)-\Pr(X\leq a)$$
Hence, for $A=(u,v)$ and $B=(s,t)$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\Pr(X\in A,Y\in B) 
&=\Pr(u\le X\le v,s\le Y\le t)\\
&=\Pr(X\le v,Y\le t)-\Pr(X\le u,Y\le t)-\Pr(X\le v,Y\le s)+\Pr(X\le u,Y\le s)\\
&=\Pr(X\le v)\Pr(Y\le t)-\Pr(X\le u)\Pr(Y\le t)-\Pr(X\le v)\Pr(Y\le s)+\Pr(X\le u)\Pr(Y\le s)\\
&=(\Pr(X\le v)-\Pr(X\le u))(\Pr(Y\le t)-\Pr(Y\le s))\\
&=\Pr(u\le X\le v)\Pr(s\le Y\le t)\\
&=\Pr(X\in A)\Pr(Y\in B)
\end{align*}$$
For any union or intersection or set differences of open intervals, you can essentially break it into a disjoint union of open intervals (you can replace any closed or semiclosed interval by an open one), say $(a_\alpha,b_\alpha)$ for $\alpha$ in some indexing set, and then use countable additivity.

Hope this helps. :)